# How can I filter and update my Django model with created_at

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models

```
class Records(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

I want cron to update `Record` every 1 minutes if `Approved` in `Request` is `True`

I tried this...

```
def user_request():
    if Request.objects.exists():
        check=Request.objects.get()
        with transaction.atomic():
            if check.Approved == True:
                Records.objects.filter(user=check.user, Date=check.Date).update(Approved=True)
                Request.objects.get().delete()
```

I dont understand why this logic wont work when this two model object was created at the same time and even when i confirm the datetime, the date, minute and second is the same.

Comment: Why are you using a `Deposit_` suffix to your model names? It should be `Records.objects` and `Request.objects` unless you're doing something like `import Records as Deposit_Records`

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake but please how can I make this work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which `Request` you want to update.

```
def user_request(req):
        req_id = req.id
        with transaction.atomic():
            if req.Approved:
                record = Records.objects.filter(user=check.user)
                record.update(Approved=True)
                req.delete()
        return req_id
```

The method `user_request` needs to be run against every request object.

An example for your CRON job:

```
from datetime import datetime
...

today_requests = Request.objects.filter(Date=datetime.today())
updated_requests = [user_request(req) for req in today_requests]
```